# When slow cooking a whole chicken for curry, should I put the vegetables in at the same time or wait?

Tags: vegetables, slow-cooking, dutch-oven

Hi guys I need some quick advice. I am about to slow cook a whole chicken and I and one question: Should I put the vegetables in while its slow cooking or will it be too mushy?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your process? How long are you planning to cook the chicken? What else is in the pot? Which vegetables are you planning to use (some need to be added in stages)... All of this info will help us give you a more useful answer.

Comment: I just threw it in: chicken more or less curry powder and extra salt for flavor. I am cooking it with coconut milk and mango. I have it ad 250 but going to cook it by ear. might bump up the temp. for veggies all I have are red and yell peppers, I will add jalapeño for heat, onions garlic and I bought a can of bamboo shoot. I think my plan it to satee them sperate. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add all of that information in so that it's easy to see.

Comment: All I wanted was advice for if I am slow cooking chicken for a few hours do I put the vegtables in with the chicken ir add them later.

Comment: We aren't really the best place for quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making, for example, chicken soup, you add the "flavoring vegetables" (onions and celery, in my experience) right at the outset, with the understanding that you'll fish them out and discard them at some point, after they've given up their flavors to the broth. The actual vegetables you want to eat go in quite a bit later. I'm pretty sure the same procedure should work for your slow-cooked curry, but I've never made curry, so temper this advice with your own good common sense.

Comment: Cool. Perfect, that was all I needed